# SCons - 'rc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: visual-studio-2005, scons, visual-studio-express, rc, tidesdk

I have set-up everything according to instructions on https://github.com/TideSDK/TideSDK/wiki/Windows7-x86-2005

But, scons won't pick up "rc" from PATH:

```
> scons -s debug=1 sdkinstaller run=1
...
runs fine for a while, until:
...
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be
removed in a future release
cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'Wp64' has been deprecated and will be
removed in a future release
boot_win32.cpp
'rc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: *** [build\win32\objs\boot\support\winboot.res] Error 1

> rc
fatal error RC1107: invalid usage; use RC /? for Help

> echo %path%
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files\Microsof
t Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tool
s;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\bin;C:\WINXP\Microsoft.NET
\Framework\v2.0.50727;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\VCPackages;C
:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16;C:\WINXP\system32;C:\WINXP;C:\WINXP\System
32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
 Files\Git\bin;C:\Python25\Scripts;C:\Python25
```

Googling on this matter suggests the solution to add the VC bin directory to PATH, but as you can see, that is already in place.

Note: I installed and used scons 2.2.0 as well, but then it wouldn't even recognize "cl". At least with scons 1.2.0 it recognizes "cl", but unfortunately not "rc"

First time building on Windows, any advice appreciated!

Comment: The issue was related to having many different versions of Visual Studio installed, and maybe when Platform SDK registered with Visual Studio, it didn't register with all of them...

After uninstalling all versions of Visual Studio Express (2005, 2008 and 2010), Platform SDK and .NET frameworks (to be sure...) and following the instructions once again (but from a clean slate), resulted in a build environment without these errors (albeit with others, but post-compilation and thus not related to this Q&A)

Comment: Did you try with the newest version? 2.3.4. You're always better starting there, rather than an old version.

Answer (score 0):

I needed multiple VC versions on my system.

By adding `print(env.Dump())` to my SConscript file I could see the paths SCons searches in to find `rc.exe`. ENV > PATH showed `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\bin\\x64` as one of the paths, while my windows kit install put the `rc.exe` and `rcdll.dll` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x64`.

Copying `rc.exe` and `rcdll.dll` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x64` solved my issues.

Same can be done for the `x86` versions of the file paths I named above.

Answer (score -2):

Might help for someone else, but Visual Studio has it's own CMD which will have these path set. Just open corresponding Visual Studio CMD and compile from there.

Comment: Since by design SCons will not import PATHS,etc from the shell it's launched in (without the user coding some logic in their SConstruct). This shouldn't help.